# Command to delete a public key from the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file?

Tags: ssh, security, openssh, key-authentication

About `SSH` - if in the **client** is executed the command:

```
ssh-keygen -R <hostname|ip>
```

The `public key(s)` of the **server** is/are removed from the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file

Now, in the **server**:

**Question**:

- Is there a command to delete the `public key` of the client stored in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file?.

It to be used mostly for *server* environments

Comment: Think of accepting answer if it fits your need ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `sed` :

```
sed -i '/ *username@client-hostname *$/d' ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

`man ssh` talk about *editing* the file, it seems there's no specific tool to achieve this simple task

Comment: I was planning on posting something similar, I usually just neovim inside and delete the lines from my ssh config. It's not done enough to warrant a tool, but if anything you could build a wrapper around sed to pass in an IP or something.